# Heat Equation 3-D

Tags: fourier-analysis

I'm new to using Mathematica software, and I need to solve a problem involving the Heat Equation for a quadrangular (3D) prism. I have the equations below and I need the temperature x time graphs; Temperature distribution on faces x, y, z in a fixed time.
Is it possible to solve in Mathematica?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm trying the solution provided by the friend below. But the software is not calculating the Anmp right. The solution should be a cosine-only function, but it is resulting in a cosine function for the first integral and sines for the last two.

Comment: Can they be converted into cosine functions? Could be MMA is just doing some cleaning up that you don't want. You could try `TrigReduce@Anmp[n,m,p]` which gives me an answer that's much nastier, but all cosines.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a starting for you,

```
u0 = 25; L1 = 1; L2 = 1; L3 = 2; alpha = 79.90*10^(-6);

Anmp[n_, m_, p_] = 
 8*u0/(L1*L2*L3)*
Integrate[Sin[n*Pi/L1*x]*Sin[m*Pi/L2*y]*Sin[p*Pi/L3*z], {z, 0, L3}, {y, 0, L2}, {x, 0, L1}]

u[x_, y_, z_, t_] = 
 Sum[Sum[Sum[Anmp[n, m, p]*Sin[n*Pi/L1*x]*Sin[m*Pi/L2*y]*Sin[p*Pi/L3*z]*
     Exp[-alpha*((n*Pi/L1)^2 + (m*Pi/L2)^2 + (p*Pi/L3)^2)*t], {p, 0, 
     Infinity}], {m, 0, Infinity}], {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

Try with `ContourPlot3D`.

Comment: The answer to the ANMP should only be a cosine function, but the software is returning a cosine and sine function.

Comment: u0 = 25; L1 = 1; L2 = 1; L3 = 2; alpha = 79.90*10^(-6);
Anmp[n_, m_, p_] = 8*u0/(L1*L2*L3)*Integrate[Sin[n*Pi*x/L1]*Sin[m*Pi*y/L2]*Sin[p*Pi*z/L3], {z, 0, L3}, {y, 0, L2}, {x, 0, L1}]

Comment: Only one correction in the position of x, y, z